# huge JTable AbstractTableModel remove all rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel, defaulttablemodel

java JTable, Say I have a huge JTable (800*50) with AbstractTableModel. Now I want to remove all table rows and put new data rows into that table. Which way is easiest and high-performance way to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Then, we will have too many code changes. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, because you don't use an AbstractTableModel. You use a model that extends AbstractTableModel. You can easily add a method to your custom model to support a refresh of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AbstractTableMoeel doesn't support this. If you extend the AbstractTableModel to create a custom model then you need to implement this method yourself.

Or you can use the DefaultTableModel which implements a setRowCount() method. So you can reset the rows to 0. You can then use the insertRow(...) method to add new rows.

However the easier way is to probably just create a new TableModel. Then you can refresh the table by using:

```
table.setModel( newlyCreatedModel );
```